# NSSPredicate variable match - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

The following expression using `NSSPredicate` will check any 'CAT' keyword is there in our data.I want to put some variable instead of the 'CAT' keyword. How can i do it, since iam a starter hope you will be kind to me.Thanks.

```
 NSPredicate *catPredicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '.*(CAT).*'"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you can construct the pattern string outside of the predicate, then configure the predicate:

```
NSString *searchString = @"CAT";
NSString *regexString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*(%@).*", searchString];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regexString];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this method in a more extended way, i.e.:

```
NSString *myString = @"CAT";    
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '.*(%@).*'",myString];
```